# While loop to repeat a series of task multiple times in C program

Tags: c, loops

I am writing a C program to repeat a series of question specified times. I ask user to enter the number of attempts they want and then I run the following while loop based on their number, but the problem is the loop keeps repeating. It does not stop at the specified number of attempt. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

    int num1,num2,high,low,average,subtotal,total_aver;

    printf("Enter number of tries you want:");
    scanf("%d", &num1);



    while (num1 < num1 + 1) {

            printf("Try number: ");
            scanf("%d", &num2);

            printf("Enter high ");
            scanf("%d", &high);

            printf("Enter low ");
            scanf("%d", &low);

            subtotal = high + low;
            total_aver = subtotal / 2;

            printf("Average temperature is: %d", total_aver);

    }

}
```

If user enters 3 for number of tries then the program should ask those question in inside the loop three times, but it keeps repeating without ending.

Comment: What values of  `a` make `a < a + 1` false? (Let's forget about overflow.)

Comment: `while (num1 < num1 + 1)` --> `while (num1--)`

Comment: If user enters 3 attempts number then a < a + 1, since a + 1 the loop will match and when it reaches a number higher then entered by user it should stop, but it does not.

Comment: @ScottSummers  Because `1`  is always smaller than `2` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  while (num1 < num1 + 1)   // condition is never false
```

Well this is infinite loop . It will continue and continue.

Write loop like this if you want to iterate number of times -

```
  int i=0;
  while(i<num1){ 
   // your code
   i++;
 }
```

Or without any extra variable -

```
 while(num1>0){
   // your code
    num1--;
 }
```

Comment: @sqykly Well did it .

Comment: it will be false when the variable is an unsigned type and wraparound

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc He doesn't have unsigned type there.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the condition in the `while` is wrong.
Infact, assigning to `num1` to any value, it will exit when `num1` will be equal to `num1+1`. Is this impossibile, isn't it? You have to use another variable to take count of times you repeat the loop.
Fix this way:

```
int count=0;
while(count<num+1){
    //your code
    count=count+1;
}
```